# When making a proof, may you use axioms backwards?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I am working on proving the following:

$$ \{\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta)\} \vdash \{ \psi \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta) \} $$

I am given the following axioms:
$$ Ax\ 1) \ \{\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi)\} $$
$$ Ax\ 2) \ \{(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta)) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow  \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) \} $$
$$ Ax\ 3) \ \{ (\lnot \psi \rightarrow \lnot \phi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \psi)\} $$

and can use Modus Ponens (MP).

Given the assumption:
$$ 1) \ \phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta) $$
Ax 2:
$$ 2) \ (\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta)) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow  \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) $$
MP 1 and 2:
$$ 3) \ ((\phi \rightarrow  \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) $$
MP 1 and 3:
$$ 4) \ (((\psi \rightarrow  \phi)\rightarrow  \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) $$

Can I then use Ax 1 backwards?
$$ 5) \ (\psi \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta)) $$

For another example, assume:
$$ (\lnot \psi \rightarrow \lnot \phi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \psi) $$
May I then use Ax 3 backwards?
$$ (\lnot \psi \rightarrow \lnot \phi) $$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using backwards"? In your first example, you appear to be replacing $((\psi \to \phi) \to \psi)$ with $\psi$, but Ax. 1 doesn't permit you to replace $\psi$ with $((\psi \to \phi) \to \psi)$. In your second example, isn't the thing you're assuming just Ax. 3?

Comment: With Ax 1, you can take an assumption $\phi$ and replace it with $\phi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$. I am wondering if you can take an assumption $\phi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$ and replace it with $\phi$. Since associativity is not part of the axioms here, that means I can't use it?

Comment: Replacing $\phi$ with $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$ isn't how an axiom like Ax. 1 is typically used. If you're doing this for a class, your instructor may be using an unusual notation, or you may have misunderstood. The typical way to "apply" an axiom like Ax. 1 would be to replace $\phi$ with $\psi \to \phi$. As for using backwards, let me go ahead and address that in an answer.

Comment: I'm reading Derek Goldrei's Propositional and Predicate Calculus. He uses Ax 1 like I said in my previous comment and then uses MP to get to $\psi\rightarrow\phi$.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, you've misunderstood - what Goldrei does is *introduce* Ax. 1. Having an axiom means that you can include it as a line of your proof whenever you want. That's not replacing $\phi$ with $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$; it's just noting $\phi$, and then noting that $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$ is also true. So Goldrei is simply taking a longer approach than the way I would "apply" the axiom - he's requiring the use of MP as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to recognize that propositional calculus isn't just symbol-pushing, it's supposed to reflect actual truth and reasoning. Think about what the step you're proposing actually says, and what your axioms say.

The axioms you have are all true statements. The first one, for example, says "if $\phi$ is true, then it is also true that *if* $\psi$ is true then $\phi$ is true". In other words, if I already know $\phi$, then I ought to be able to infer $\psi \to \phi$. But notice that the same line of thinking doesn't work in reverse: if I know that $\phi$ *would* be true if $\psi$ were, that doesn't allow me to infer that $\phi$ is actually true! It's certainly the case that *if* fire were cold *then* you could safely put your hand in it, but most of us agree that one ought not put your hand in fire.

That example should tell you that, in general, **an axiom and its "backwards" version are not interchangeable**. In rare cases, you can reverse an axiom safely, but usually not.